# How to parse HTML tags from a string in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a blog from the ground up, as practice. I am storing my post body in MongoDB and it stores as a massive string. I have added some random html tags into that string for testing. What is the usual way of parsing that long string so that the html tags are read and then used?

Stack is: JavaScript / React / Express / MongoDB

Some code:

```
    function Posts({ posts }) {
  const postLis = posts.map((post) => {
    return (
      <li key={post._id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>

        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{postLis}</ul>;
}
```

My testing JSON:

```
{
"posts": [
{
"_id": "5f7af2f468478387e792a522",
"title": "Welcome to Explore Edinburgh(express test 1)",
"featuredPhoto": "/432425521",
"date": "10th September 2020, 14:25",
"tags": [
"edinburgh",
"explore edinburgh"
],
"body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum condimentum, quam vel<br>porta porta, elit mauris viverra diam, et pharetra nisl lorem<br>eget neque."
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
function Posts({ posts }) {
  const postLis = posts.map((post) => {
    return (
      <li key={post._id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>

        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.body }}></p>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{postLis}</ul>;
}
```

If you want to parse it because you cannot ensure the content is safe, you can use [`html-react-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser):

```
use { parse } from 'html-react-parser';

function Posts({ posts }) {
  const postLis = posts.map((post) => {
    return (
      <li key={post._id}>
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>

        <p>{parse(post.body)}></p>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return <ul>{postLis}</ul>;
}
```